# How do I check if URL path strictly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

In my controller method

I want to know if the URL path is /404 but not /task/id/95404

```
  redirect_url = request.original_fullpath.include?("404") ? root_path : request.original_url
```

Comment: are you checking this at  controller side?

Comment: Why would you actually need this? This should be handled by your routes.

Comment: i need it to create a redirect url for link that uses an external app

Comment: yes this is in my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying regex expression to find exact url match?
May be try this regex : ^/page$
Here ^ represents starting and $ is the ending of matching string for the url  you want to get matched. 
so just replace the word page with 404.
Final regex expression : ^/page$

Answer (score 0):

In case of url path `/404` you will get a id in params hash with value = 404 otherwise you will get value of id is 95404

so here you can also check it like this: -

```
redirect_url =  params[:id] == 404 ? root_path : request.original_url
```

Comment: @ZenaMesfin lets put value in string like this `params[:id] == "404"`

Comment: i don't know if you can actually do that?